# popper.js: boundariesElement and escapeWithReference does not work together?

Tags: javascript, typescript, popper.js

how can i have the boundariesElement and escapeWithReferance properties to work together.. I am a facing an issue now: the popper overflows outside the boundary when both `boundariesElement` and `esapeWithReference: true` properties are set.

[image]